# Color a 3d surface created using curve3d (R package:emdbook) according to value of z

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I'm plotting a 3D surface in R using the curve3d function from the emdbook package. An example:

```
curve3d(expr=219.4*exp(-0.5*(((x--1.3)/0.6)^2+((y-2.4)/0.8)^2))+ 
          80.1*exp(-0.5*(((x-0.1)/0.7)^2+((y--1.3)/0.4)^2))+
          52.1*exp(-0.5*(((x-0.2)/0.5)^2+((y-0.8)/0.5)^2)),
          from = c(-3,-3), to = c(3,5), n = 50, sys3d = "persp",
          theta=145,phi=30,zlab="z")
```

Now, I'd like to colour the surface according to the z value. I've looked at the example for the persp function where the surface is coloured according to z, but that's not helpful because I'm not defining z myself when using curve3d. Is there a way to do this using curve3d?